# To set colour using javascript for specific column cell conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this javascript below and I'm trying to set the colour of the value in the cell conditionally to the same colour as the background of that column if it is equal to 0:

```
$(function(){
  var columnindex = $('th:contains("Q1 Spells")').index();

if(columnindex != -1)
  {
      $('tr').each(function() {
          var column = $('td', this).eq(columnindex);

          switch (column.text())
          {
              default:
                  column.css({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'});
                  if(column.value === 0) {
                      column.css({color: '#FF0000'});
                  }
                  break;
          }
      });
  }
)};
```

I can't seem to get this to work for the cell colour (background setting works fine) - How do I achieve this?

Comment: A `switch` with only a `default` case?  A table cell has no `value`, `column.value === 0` -> `column.text() === "0"`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, that's sorted it, silly error. I removed the other code for brevity from the switch :)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
if(columnindex === 0) {
    column.css("color", "#FF0000");
}
```

If that doesn't work check to see if you have a CSS declaration overriding it somewhere, such as with !important.

Also verify there isn't a child HTML element whose style is overriding the column's css color.